# Eclipse + RunJettyRun + Spring MVC: how to set SSL for testing?

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, eclipse-plugin, runjettyrun

I am using Eclipse (Luna) and RunJettyRun to develop a Spring MVC website on Windows 7. I would like to test whether it works on SSL for certain pages or directories.

I have a self-assigned SSL certificate (file: .keystore) in C:\Users\Me with the default password "changeit".

In my Spring's security context, I have the following:

```
<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" request-matcher="regex" >

    ....

    <intercept-url pattern="^\/login$" requires-channel="https"  />

    <port-mappings>
        <port-mapping http="8080" https="8443"/>
   </port-mappings>
</http>
```

When I click http://localhost:8080/login, I am redirected to https://localhost:8443/login (which works as expected) and I get the following message in Chrome:

```
This webpage is not available
```

This is understandable because I haven't setup anything for port 8443.

How to set SSL for port 8443 in my situation? Googled quite a bit, but what I found is mostly about setup for standalone Jetty.

Thanks for any pointers and input!